# Cannot use 2 Email forms on iOS website?

Tags: iphone, ios, forms

I am having an issue on a Mobile WordPress site.

At the bottom of the page is the standard post comment form which ask for a users email, below that form I have another separate form that is used as a Contact form in the footer of the page.

No matter what I do, when I select the Footer Contact forms email field on an iOS device, it automaticly jumps focus to the Comment forms email field instead.

Both forms are inside there own  tags with different names and id's

Both the email fields do have the `id="email"` but that's what is needed for the back-end, at least for the name fields.

This is an issue I have never seen and my initial search has found no help.

Any ideas how to fix?

---

**UPDATE**

Testing in Chrome on Desktop does the same affect, clicking the second Email form, automatically brings Focus to the 1st email input form

Comment: If both fields have `id="email"` then the HTML markup is invalid.  `id` needs to be unique.  The `name` value probably shouldn't be repeated either, though I don't know if that's invalid or not.  Usually when multiple inputs have the same `name` it looks something like: `name="email[]"`.

Comment: @David Yeah I just fixed that issue but my problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  My Form had a `<label for="email">` field which was switching focus to the other email field